# How do I update WordPress on OpenShift?

Tags: wordpress, openshift

I am currently hosting a site on OpenShift that is running WordPress, version 3.8.11. The source is a copy of this: https://github.com/openshift/wordpress-example. The site is load-balanced across multiple servers.

I would like to update the core version of WordPress and the plugins. I know how to update the the plugins I added (make the changes in the source control, and push the changes), but there are several plugins that seem to come with the installation by default.

I know that if I update the plugins and/or Wordpress through the website, that the update won't automatically bubble out to *all* the servers the site is hosted on.

So, how can I update Wordpress and the default plugins to *all* servers hosting the site?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you need more control over your WordPress installation on OpenShift. You can proceed as indicated in [Deploying WordPress on OpenShift](https://developers.openshift.com/en/php-wordpress.html), i.e. using the [OpenShift Developer WordPress Quickstart](https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/openshift-wordpress-developer-quickstart).

According to the documentation, you can upgrade the WordPress locally and push it to OpenShift using version control then, the same as you're updating some of the plugins now.

Comment: So are you saying there's no other way than destroying what I currently have, and then re-doing the whole thing with the WordPress core included this time?

Comment: @dochoffiday, I do not recommend dumping all what you have on your current WordPress instance. In regards of content, you can export your WP database and import it into the new instance (after setting up the new instance, drop the tables and import everything from the old one, into the new database).

Answer (score 0):

You can always update your wordpress & plugins from the wp-admin dashboard. I have a scalable wordpress instance running the latest version of wordpress on OpenShift. I have updated all my plugins to the latest version.
 Hope you meant gears when you mentioned "servers".